# Sharepoint search API array transform to standard format

Tags: arrays, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I would like to transform array from search sharepoint rest API of objects like this:

```
Object
Key:"Path"
Value:"https://host.com/file.pdf"
ValueType:"Edm.String"
```

To standard format like:

```
Object
Path: "https://host.com/file.pdf"
```

What is the best way? I was looking for solution in lodash documentation but I found nothing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look.

```
var reformattedArray = function(obj){
    var rObj = {}; 
    for(var i=0;props > i;i++){
      rObj[obj[i].Key] = obj[i].Value;
    }
    return rObj;
};
console.log(reformattedArray(<array to be transformed>));
```

Now my array is transformed to requied format.